# What are the hardware requirements for Joomla 4.x

Tags: joomla-4.x

My development site went down because the server was taking 7 seconds to respond. The load balancer thought it was dead. So gave 503 errors.

It makes me wonder if I need a bigger server.

What are the recommended/requirements for a joomla 4.x install?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for joomla 4.x: https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements

However, **your issue may be caused by a bug in the `System - WebAuthn Passwordless Login`** Plugin.

- Bug report: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/38662
- Fix (a PR for next Joomla release): https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/38664
- A temporary workaround is to disable the `System - WebAuthn Passwordless Login` plugin.

Comment: These are software stack requirements not hardware requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up though.  I'll give that a try as I'm not using that feature yet.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know about hardware requirements. However, I managed to run Joomla 3 on a Raspberry Pi 1B using Nginx as web server. :-)